# d3.select() not selecting the div

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am a newbie with d3 JS and i was into my first try to draw a graph with d3. I have the following HTML and JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>D3 JS</title>
    <style>
        .container{
            width: 300px;
            height: 260px;
        }
        .bar{
            background-color: aquamarine;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
    </style>
        </style>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

```
const DUMMY_DATA = [
  { id: "d1", value: 10, region: "India" },
  { id: "d2", value: 15, region: "Germany" },
  { id: "d3", value: 12, region: "UK" },
  { id: "d4", value: 8, region: "Netherlands" },
  { id: "d5", value: 19, region: "Norway" },
];

const container = d3
  .select("div")
  .classed("container", true)
  .style("border", "2px solid red");

const bars = container
  .selectAll(".bar")
  .data(DUMMY_DATA)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .classed("bar", true)
  .style("width", "30px")
  .style("height", ((data) => data.value * 10) + "px");
```

I am trying to draw simple bar chart and i have no error in the console. but the class i am trying to add to the div is not appending in the DOM and hence the remaining this are not getting plotted. can anyone tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: Did you try by adding script at last?(after the div)

Comment: @AnuragDas. Yes did

Answer (score 0):

Your height problem is your parenthesis. But you still don't have a proper chart otherwise:

```
.style("height", (data) => data.value * 10 + "px")
```